# Where on projected elements does not include where in query

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I have the following case:

```
foos.Select(f => new Bar { 
    A = f.A, 
    B = f.B, 
    C = f.C == null ? "Yes" : "No",
    D = 10,
    E = f.SubObject.Value
})
.Where(b => b.C == "Yes")
```

now it seems that this generates something along the lines of:

```
SELECT 
    [f0].[A],
    [f0].[B],
    CASE WHEN [f0].[C] IS NULL N'Yes' ELSE N'No' END AS [C],
    10 AS [D],
    [f.SubObject0].[Value] AS [E]
FROM [foos] AS [f0]
LEFT JOIN [SubObjects] AS [f.SubObject0]
   ON [f0].[ObjectID] = [f.SubObject0].[ObjectId]
```

But it doesn't include the where clause. Is there a way to force it in there? seeing now it will grab all the entities in the foos table before doing the where, which ofc is extremely slow.

Comment: What is `foos` in this example?

Comment: foos would be a DbSet<Foo> foos;

Comment: Are you absolutely sure? It hasn't, for example, been cast to an `IEnumerable<Foo>` along the way?

Comment: Hmm good point, I'll doublecheck directly on the context

Comment: Yup directly on the context it has the same issue

Comment: So `context.Foos.Where(...)` is doing this? What provider are you using? Is this the entire query? Do you have a `GroupBy` perhaps?

Comment: Yup, I'm using MsSQL as provider and yes this is the entire query.

Comment: Possibly the MySQL provider isn't working correctly then. Which version are you using?

Comment: MSSQL not MySQL and it's from Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.7

Comment: There's something you're not sharing with us, something as simple as what you have presented above should work fine. Do you have a peculiar entity setup or context?